# Please do tell me why my question here was deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

The question I posted here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23711342/why-learn-svg-is-it-worth-the-efforts

I was not given any warning, but directly got my question deleted. Please do tell what was so offensive about it?

Comment: Your question was opinion based, nothing offensive, but opinion based questions are not entertained here, google up if you want to learn the advantages and disadvantages

Comment: I think that most misunderstood the question, as it rather answers itself. Naturally people use a drawing program to draw complex designs, then export it to svg format.

Comment: In addition to being closed, the question was deleted by 3 community members, most likely because they felt that the post wasn't salvageable. I don't agree with the fast-deletion here; you didn't  get a chance to learn why it was closed. But even if not deleted by community members, your post would be auto-deleted if still closed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters do you think the post is salvageable?

Comment: Sarabjeet, nothing to get hurt about.. just roam around SO and different stackexchange domain.. it may happen that your question is belonging to or more suitable to different domain and accidentally or unknowingly you've put that question on another one..

Comment: @MattBall: no, but I don't see a point in deleting something that'll be auto-deleted anyway. Was it doing active harm?

Comment: If auto-deletion is inevitable then there's no real harm in aggressively deleting.

Comment: Stop downvoting and just tell the reason guys.. it makes no sense here as it is just a discussion..

Comment: @Mr_Green: the OP states it would have been reasonable for him/her to postpone deleting until s/he could have read the reason. I disagree -- should SO have kept it "visible" until we are *sure* he had a chance to? When would that have been?

Comment: I was confused when I first looked at the question because it appeared that the OP posted this *before* the question got deleted. Turns out it had been deleted about half an hour after it was first posted, then undeleted recently, then deleted again 2 minutes later. Do you people really have nothing better to do with your votes? Sheesh.

Comment: Starbucks doesn't take my votes @BoltClock.

Comment: Lets reopen it again!  Votes are in plenty today, not many questions around.

Comment: @Guffa Actually, there are many, many uses for SVG that don't involve Illustrator. For example [this calculator](http://phrogz.net/tmp/ScreenDensityCalculator.html) of mine uses SVG (on Chrome/Safari) for a dynamic image, or [this page](http://phrogz.net/SVG/TurtleTest.html) that explores some interesting turtle graphics, or [this](http://phrogz.net/svg/stirling_numbers.xhtml) visual demonstration of Stirling Numbers, or [this](http://phrogz.net/SVG/soldiers.xhtml) visual exploration of a logic problem.

Comment: @Phrogz: Yes, but the OP specifically asked about complex designs.

Answer (score 7):

I can only assume that you did not read the "reason for close" which is displayed below your question, so here it is again:

[image]

Please let me know if you still cannot find the text to which I am referring.

Comment: That's the close reason, OP is asking for the deletion reason ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Closing a question is the first step toward deletion. The reason a question is deleted *is* the reason why it was closed.

Comment: @hichris123: I think he was making a joke.

Comment: @BoltClock Oh, okay... not obvious to me except for the `;)`. thanks.

Comment: OP is new, confusion could have (probably) been avoided with a link to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The Help Center [has been around since 2013-06-03](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161595/235574). Before that we had the FAQ, so there has always been somewhere to point the new-comers.